# Bootloader timing tool for Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Does anyone know which tool can measure the boot time from Power On to at least when the kernel starts to load on Ubuntu?

I've tried Bootchart,but it doesn't appear to measure the time from power on.

Thanks for any help.